# Can someone explain this switching techniques solution?

Tags: networking

In Data Communications and Networks: An Engineering Approach book By James Irvine, David Harle, the below appears.

How do they get to that answer?

The closest I can get is 180 seconds.

[image]

Comment: I believe that answer explains it completely and correctly. It is simple math. I ran it through a calculator, and I came up with the same answer as the answer in the book.

Comment: 1 Mbyte = 1024*1024*8 bits. Don't ask me why or how that and 1 kbit = 1000 bits could both be true at the same time though.

Comment: @RonMaupin Maybe it's just me, but there seems to be some inconsistent conversion when you look at 1 Mbyte = 1024*1024*8 bits versus 1 kbit = 1000 bits.

Comment: @Dukeling, not really. Carriers use multiples of 1000 bits for their circuits, and then call that a kilobit, and that is not really incorrect. On the other hand computer systems need to use powers of two, and 1024 is close to 1000, so the term kilo has been applied to computer systems for 1024; it is somewhat inaccurate but close.

Comment: Can one of ye please explain the math to be please?

Answer (score 0):

1.4 MBytes in bits = 1.4*1024*1024*8 = 11744051.2 bits.
11744051.2/64000 = 183.5 seconds.